# AssertionError: Unexpected type. Expected 'list' got '<class 'str'>' erorr in create Azure Databricks with Pulumi Azure Native

Tags: python, azure, pulumi

I want to create Azure Databricks with Pulumi from this [document](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azure-native/databricks/workspace/).

My code is :

```
databricks_workspace = azure_native.databricks.Workspace('databrick',
                                                         location=location_name,
                                                         resource_group_name=resource_group.name,
                                                         managed_resource_group_id=pulumi.Output.all(
                                                             resource_group.id),
                                                         workspace_name='workspace-{}-{}'.format(
                                                             project_name, stack_name),
                                                         sku=azure_native.databricks.SkuArgs(
                                                             name='Standard',
                                                             tier='Standard'
                                                         ),
                                                         tags={
                                                             'Team': 'Data',
                                                             'Environment': stack_name,
                                                         },
                                                         )
```

The input of `managed_resource_group_id` is the output of `resource_group`. When I run this code I received this error:

```
raise AssertionError(f"Unexpected type. Expected 'list' got '{typ}'")
AssertionError: Unexpected type. Expected 'list' got '<class 'str'>'
error: an unhandled error occurred: Program exited with non-zero exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I see without running your code is that `managed_resource_group_id` should be a string but you pass a result of `pulumi.Output.all` to it. Could you try changing to

```
managed_resource_group_id=resource_group.id,
```

Comment: Yes, that's true. Other things the `managed_resource_group_id` should be different from the application's resource group.